# Horizontal OptionGroup in a Table (Vaadin)

Tags: java, vaadin

I' tryind to add an OptionGroup to my table, but so far the table stays empty no matter what I do.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    table = new Table();
    table.setSizeFull();
    table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
    table.addContainerProperty("Option one", OptionGroup.class, null);
    table.addContainerProperty("Option two", OptionGroup.class, null);
    opt1 = new OptionGroup("");
    opt1.addItem();     
    opt1.addItem();
    opt1.setMultiSelect(false);
    table.addItem(new Object[] {"Name one", opt1.getItem(1),opt1.getItem(2)}, new Integer(1));
```

Am I missing something, or is it not so easy to solve this as shown in my example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick look, but it seem you are not adding any Option Group Options.

Have you tried just addeding the Option class itself

```
table = new Table();
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Option one", OptionGroup.class, null);
opt1 = new OptionGroup("Time");
opt1.addItem("AM");     
opt1.addItem("PM");
table.addItem(new Object[] {"Name one", opt1}, new Integer(1));
```

I would also remove the *setSizeFull()*

Also the *null*, will be the default value if something goes wrong.

once you have that working, you can use CSS to arrange the options Horizontally.

Comment: I actually want to put the items of the Optiongroup by cell. e.g in the first cell i have the Name of the option and in the second cell i want to put the first option of my optionGroup and in the third cell i want to put the second option of my optionGroup is it even possible ?

Comment: Not sure how you would split across different cells, but b using css you can create borders per items. So you can use css to display the option horizontally. if you can do this, is your requirement for each options to be in its own table cell is removed ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use the [FlexibleOptionGroup](http://vaadin.com/addon/flexibleoptiongroup) add-on.